# Trying to create a matrix list of excel rows as dictionary keys

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, dictionary, matrix

I am trying create a dictionary of matrix or double arrays[list] in python and this is what I have so far. I created the dictionary already and assigned it the proper keys. I have an excel file that I was able to successfully parse a but the first row of the excel table contains duplicate UPN numbers at times (aka car parts that can fit multiple cars) I want to scan this portion of the row and compare it to the row after and if they match then assign it to a matrix and have that be the value of the key (which is going to be the UPN aka the part that may fit multiple cars). But I can't seem to crack it. I am sort of new to python and this is a low pay gig but still. What the heck is going on?

```
import csv
import collections
import sys
from collections import defaultdict
from Car_of_Interest import Car_of_Interest
import json
import numbers
import enum
import pickle
import shelve
#import dill as pickle

carDataFrame = {}

def main ():

    data = csv.open(r"C:\Users\Ultrarev\Desktop\Duplicator-fier\Book1.csv")
    data = csv.reader(data)

    print("Data: (testing)")

def f7(seq):
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    return [x for x in seq if not (x in seen or seen_add(x))]

with open(r"C:\Users\Ultrarev\Desktop\Emeran-Parser\Book1.csv", newline = '') as csvfile:
    data = csv.reader(csvfile)
    rowExcel = []
    kPN = []
    car_info = []
    UPN = ()
    cUPN = []
    CARS = {}
    #UPN_len = len(UPN)
    for row in data:
        open(r"C:\Users\Ultrarev\Desktop\Emeran-Parser\Book1.csv")
        rowExcel.append(row)

        car_info.append(row[2])
        car_info.append(row[3])
        car_info.append(row[4])

        #print('-> '.join(row))
    for row in rowExcel:
        kPN.append(row[0])

# Convert to string.
list1 = kPN
str1 = ' '.join(str(e) for e in list1)

#Remove Duplicates in kPN.
UPN = f7(kPN)


l = UPN.__sizeof__()

print("kPN: ")
print(kPN)
print("Data: ")
print(data)
print("UPN: ")
print(UPN)
print("Major Car Information of File to be Parsed into HTML: ")
print(rowExcel)
print("Number of UPN's: ")
print(len(UPN))
print(len(kPN))
#for n in UPN:
data = open(r"C:\Users\Ultrarev\Desktop\Emeran-Parser\Book1.csv")

#create the foundation of the dictionary.
mydict=dict()
SANAD = []
for n in range(len(UPN)):
    if (rowExcel[n][0] == rowExcel[n+1][0]):
        while (rowExcel[n][0] == rowExcel[n+1][0]):
            SANAD.append(rowExcel[n])

    mydict.update({UPN[n]: SANAD})  #'tag %s' % n


print(mydict)
```

I am expecting mydict to print a dictionary with the UPN's as keys and the values as a matrix of rows with the same UPN. I am also expecting that my Python knowledge is not up to par for this project.

EDIT:

I created two other classes one called Car_of_Interest.py which would be a kind of factory class that produces car_I objects that store each cars information.

```
import pickle
#import dill
class Car_I:
    def init(self,year,make,model,car_I):
        data.self = data
        x.self = year
        y.self = make
        z.self = model

        data = {"year":year,
                "mode":model,
                "make":make
                }

    def __add__(self, other):
        return 1
    def printData(self):
        print(x, y , z)

    def honk_the_Horn(self):
        print("Honk! Honk!")
    def PRINT_Dic(self):
        L = {}
        L = {UPN:(x,y,z)}
        print(L)

    def make_INTERNAL_LABEL(self,label):
        lUPN.self = label
        return("lUPN")
```

```
import pickle
#import dill
class Car_I:
    def init(self,year,make,model,car_I):
        data.self = data
        x.self = year
        y.self = make
        z.self = model

        data = {"year":year,
                "mode":model,
                "make":make
                }

    def __add__(self, other):
        return 1
    def printData(self):
        print(x, y , z)

    def honk_the_Horn(self):
        print("Honk! Honk!")
    def PRINT_Dic(self):
        L = {}
        L = {UPN:(x,y,z)}
        print(L)

    def make_INTERNAL_LABEL(self,label):
        lUPN.self = label
        return("lUPN")
```

Would storing this information as a matrix OR going the car_of_Interest ->Car_I(n...) be a better approach?

Comment: {UPN...n:[[x,y,z]...[x,y,z,...n]...n]

Comment: Can you guys critique or demonize me. I have been able to assign each UPN an object (which I know is different b.c. the hexadecimal memory address of the pointer in python is different per every run).... I am thinking of storing each multiple of kPN's to a dictionary within the object and pickling it and then shelving OR going the my "orthodox" route and having each UPN -> object_factory->cars...n In many situiations an indexing of such information via SQLlite may be of need.